# How to update Active Directory on Server 2008 R2 to enable GPO management of Windows 10 clients

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I am working on a stand alone network with no internet connection. The Active Directory Server is running on Windows Server 2008 R2. We received some new client workstations running Windows 10 version 1607. I've been trying to create policies to disable the Windows 10 Metro Apps, OneDrive and other features the users should not have access to or should not be enabled as there is no internet on the network however the version of Active Directory on Server 2008 R2 does not have the GPO settings the newer Windows 10 features. What is the proper procedure to add the latest Windows 10 features to be show in Group Policy Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Group Policy Central Store on the domain controller, download or copy the Windows 10 AMDX files from a Windows 10 client to the store directory to use the policies. In your case, copy them from one of the clients:

First, create the Group Policy Central Store, this is done by creating a folder named `PolicyDefinitions` in the following location 
 `\\contoso.com\SYSVOL\contoso.com\policies` where contoso.com is your domain name.

Next up, find the AMDX files from a Windows 10 client. These are found at the following location `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions`. Copy them to  `\\contoso.com\SYSVOL\contoso.com\policies\PolicyDefinitions`. After this you will be able to deploy Windows 10 policies